# Spring geospatial library

Tags: library, java, geometry, geography

I am developing a project in spring. Is there a library for working with geospatial data (with geometry and geography), if I need to check the intersections of geometries, the occurrence of one polygon in another, the occurrence of a geographic coordinate in a certain geometry, calculate the distance from one geographic coordinate to another geographic coordinate? I know there is Postgis in postgres, I need the same functionality on the middle layer.

I searched the geotools library, but I never managed to add it to the project, so I don’t even know if it is suitable for these tasks

Answer (score 0):

There are Java bindings for GDAL and OGR.  https://gdal.org/api/java/index.html  and https://gdal.org/java/